# JQuery Form JSON response data NULL in Internet Explorer

Tags: json, internet-explorer, spring-mvc, jquery-forms-plugin

I am using [Malsup's JQuery Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) with Spring MVC to do some Ajax lookups.

I am encountering an issue with IE (surprise surprise).

Javascript Code:

```
var options = {
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    success: displayList,
    error: errorList,
    url: 'test.jsp',
    dataType: 'json'
};

$('form').ajaxSubmit(options);

function displayPolicyList(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)
{
    alert(responseText); // Works in all browsers
}


function errorList(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
{
    alert(xhr.responseText); // Fine in firefox etc, NULL in IE
}
```

Spring Code:

```
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> erroResponse()
{
    Map<String, String> error = new TreeMap<String, String>();

    error.put("error", message);

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);

    return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>>(error, responseHeaders,
                                              HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

All works fine in all browsers on success. I can read and parse the JSON response without any issues. The problem arises when I return 500 with my error messages in the JSON response. In firefox, chrome etc, it all woks as expected and errorList can parse the JSON response.

In IE however the JSON is null. I can see in the JQuery Form plugin that I receive the same cross origin error (**cannot access response document: TypeError: Access is denied.**
) detailed here:

[Access is denied. on jquery.form.js in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933868/access-is-denied-on-jquery-form-js-in-ie)

I am not however accessing cross domain as it is a single application.

In the JQuery Plugin the block that seems to be the issue is:

```
function getDoc(frame) {
        var doc = frame.contentWindow ? frame.contentWindow.document : frame.contentDocument ? frame.contentDocument : frame.document;
        return doc;
    }
```

When I return HttpStatus.CREATED from the Controller it works fine, but any failure event from the server causes the above function to throw an exception.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your submitted form have a file field which is being submitted?

Comment: It does. It all works in the case of a successful response from the Controller. Where the problem lies is when I return 500 from the Controller based on some internal validation of the submitted data.

Comment: Do you have special handling in place for the "normal" response such that the JSON is returned in a TEXTAREA? When I submit a form with this plugin, which form has a file input and is coming from IE, I must wrap JSON responses in a TEXTAREA because of the pseudo-ajax (via iframe) IE requires. You'll need to add the same special handling in the 500 response.

Comment: Are you talking about the fact the IE tries to save JSON responses instead of printing them? I've added the exact same handling for both success and error resposnes. From my code above if I change HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR to HttpStatus.OK, the getDoc(frame) function works, but that is no good as the response is identified as a success response and I'd prefer not to have to do an ugly hack to print error messages

Comment: If I read you correctly, no, I am not referring to that. I am referring to the third paragraph at http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. If I inspect the response message in JQuery Form plugin I see that in the case where I return 500 frame.contentWindow and frame.contentDocument throws and Access Denied. The structure, headers and content of what I return is exactly the same in both cases. The only difference is HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR to HttpStatus.OK

Comment: My only other suggestion, which would rule out what I suggested as an issue, is to remove the file field and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I think this may be something similar, but without a fix. http://stackoverflow.com/a/151404/2028936

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message because my response contained the following http header:

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

Removing it or changing the header value to SAMEORIGIN solved it for me.

More reading here:
http://blog.mozilla.org/security/2010/09/08/x-frame-options/